# Declare and <DllImport> in VB.NET have different results

Tags: dllimport, declare

I've been trying to call a login method of an unmanaged DLL.

If I use Declare the login fails.

```
Private Declare Function Login Lib "dllCore" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpPassword As String) As Int32

Login ("Steve", "123456") ' THIS FAILS TO LOGIN ALTHOUGH THE PARAMS ARE CORRECT
```

If I use DllImport, it works !!

```
    <DllImport("dllCore.dll", 
                EntryPoint:="Login", 
                SetLastError:=True, 
                CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, 
                ExactSpelling:=True, 
                CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> 
        Private Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Integer
        End Function

Login ("Steve", "123456") ' NOW WORKS
```

Has anyone any ideas why I get this behaviour ??

Answer (score 1):

The default character set for a Declare statement is Ansi. You need to set the charset to Unicode to properly match the DllImport.

```
Private Declare Unicode Function Login Lib "dllCore" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpPassword As String) As Int32
```

[MSDN documentation for the Declare statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zey12w5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)